# Identify this sprawling vine with five-lobed leaves with serrated edges

Tags: identification, vines

Can anyone identify this vine? It's currently growing on the ground, as it has nothing to climb, and it's sending out long shoots in several directions. I'm in zone 7a if that helps at all.

*Click for full size*

[image: Unknown vine]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is [Virginia Creeper (Parthenocissus quinqefolia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenocissus_quinquefolia) on the basis of the five serrated leaves that have holes in the leaves that are the typical signs of being eaten by the [grape flea beetle](http://www.extension.umn.edu/distribution/horticulture/m1236.html).

This plant is a robust climber that is not be treated lightly.  It is a member of the grape family and around this time of the year you can often find the small pea sized purple berries. It turns a vibrant red and is very attractive at this time of the year.

It has been known to cover houses and was described by Trevor Cole, former curator of the Arboretum in Ottawa where I live as the only plant he knew that could be planted upside down and still live.

This is a plant to place far away from delicate plants and structures as it will overgrow them.  I have one that is fighting it out with my cedar hedge and Explorer rose bush.  So far it has not ripped out the chain link fence it is growing on....

Comment: This plant will have to go, but now that I've seen some photos of what it will look like in the fall, I think I'll attempt to root some cuttings to plant under a large willow tree. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think it is Virginia Creeper, a pretty agressive weed (in my opinion).  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_creeper

Answer (score 1):

These Virginia creepers will take over everything in their paths.  The only thing I've come across to eradicate  them is roundup and plenty of it!!!  they also spread around the neighborhoods like wild fire!  Drought doesn't seem to hurt them though if your after foliage!